# Reverting from paid to free Azure SQL database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

A couple of months ago I set up a new website on Azure and opted in to create a free 20MB database with it. Everything has been fine, up until a couple weeks ago when I suddenly started getting charged for my database. After raising a ticket, I was told that my database had somehow moved onto the standard 0-100mb option. I don't remember doing this, however, I was wondering if there was a way of reverting it back to the free version. It's a little annoying as my database is only about 3mb in size and is not holding much data or used intensively.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there isn't a way.  It was my understanding that when you sign up for Azure you get a 90 day free trial [assuming you stay within the confines of the free trial resource limits].  At the end of the trial you will begin to be billed

EDIT:
It seems that the 90 day trial is no longer valid...

Old offer: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0018p/

New Offer: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0044p/